# Delete a range elements in a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to delete some elements in my vector, which are specified by another index vector. I get a segmentation fault. The reason why I get a segmentation fault is that the size of my vector decrease as the elements get deleted, so it seem like I'm trying to exceed the index. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
int a = 5, b = 10 , c = 20, d = 30, e = 40 , f = 50;
vector<int> vec;

vec.push_back(a);
vec.push_back(b);
vec.push_back(c);
vec.push_back(d);
vec.push_back(e);
vec.push_back(f);

vector<int> index_2_b_el;

index_2_b_el.push_back(1); //delete b
index_2_b_el.push_back(3); //delete d
index_2_b_el.push_back(4); //delete e

for(int i=0; i<index_2_b_el.size(); i++)
{
    vec.erase(vec.begin() + index_2_b_el[i]);
    // "b", "d" and "e" should be deleted
}   

for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
{
    cout<< "vec: "<< vec[i]<<endl;
    // "a", "c" and "f" should remain
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you do _not_ access elements out of the valid range of your vector?

Comment: I think I do access elements out of the valid range, because if the first two elements are deleted, size goes to 4 so the last deletion tries to deletes the fourth one which does not exist.

Comment: Well spotted. How about _not_ doing it, then? Design your algorithm so that what you **know** you are doing wrong isn't done anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say the size of the vector changes, also note the indices change too so you're not removing the elements you think you are. May I suggest sorting the index vector (`std::sort`), and then removing from the largest index down. That way the previous indices are not invalidated by the removal of the ones before.

Answer (score -1):

`vec.begin() + index_2_b_el[i]` is an interator and erase invalidate all iterators to the erased elements and to the elements between them and the end of the container are invalidated. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

So after the first erase, `vec.begin() + index_2_b_el[1]` and `vec.begin() + index_2_b_el[2]` are no longer valid

The best solution is to use [Erase-remove_idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)

Comment: The vec.begin() gets called after each call to vec.erase. That is the iterator gets invalidated, but then it is thrown away and recomputed.

Comment: My bad, i didn't see that it was vec.begin() and not a once acquiered iterator. But the best solution is still Erase-remove idiom